# Rails nested attributes are not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, persistence

I am new to rails and am learning to complete an Inventory System database project for school.

Here is my Item model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key ='item_id'

  validates :item_id, :presence => true

  has_one :vendor_item, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :vendor, :through => :vendor_item

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vendor_item
end
```

Here is my item controller:

```
    class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
      @item = Item.new
      @all_vendors = Vendor.all
      @item_vendor = @item.build_vendor_item

  end

    def create
     @item = Item.new(item_params)


     vendor = params[:vendors][:id]
     @item_vendor = @item.build_vendor_item(:vendor_id => vendor)
     @item_vendor.save

     #raise params.inspect
     if @item.save
       redirect_to @item
     else 
       render 'new'
     end
    end

    def show
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
      @item_vendor = @item.vendor_item

    end

    def index
      @items = Item.all

    end

    def priceUnder500
      @priceUnder500 = Item.where("price < ?", 500)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
      end
    end

    def priceOver500
      @priceOver500 = Item.where("price > ?", 500)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
      end
    end

    def edit
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
      @all_vendors = Vendor.all    
      @vendor_item = @item.vendor_item
    end

    def update
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
      vendor = params[:vendors][:id]    

      if @item.vendor_item.blank?   
      @item.build_vendor_item(:vendor_id => vendor)
    end


      if @item.update(params[:item].permit(:item_id, :name, :category, :description, :reorder_level, :quantity, :price, :vendor_item_attributes => [:vendor_item_id]))  
        redirect_to items_path
      else 
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
      @item.destroy


      redirect_to items_path
    end



    private
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:item_id, :name, :category, :description, :reorder_level, :quantity, :price, :vendor_item_attributes => [:vendor_item_id])
    end
  end
```

And my _form partial for items:

```
   <%= form_for @item do |f| %>
  <% if @item.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@item.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this post from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @item.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :item_id, 'Item Id' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :item_id %>
  </p>

  <%= fields_for @item_vendor do |vii| %>
  <div class= "vendorItemId">

  <%= vii.label :vendor_item_id%>
  <%= vii.text_field :vendor_item_id%><br>

  </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :category %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :category %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :reorder_level %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :reorder_level %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :quantity %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :quantity %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </p>

  <h3>Vendors:</h3>
  <%= fields_for(@item_vendor) do |ab| %>
  <div class= "field">

    <%= ab.label "All Vendors:" %><br>
    <%= collection_select(:vendors, :id, @all_vendors, :id, :name, {},{:multiple => false})%>
  </div>
  <% end %>


  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

vendor_item contains a reference to item_id, vendor_id, and has another attribute of vendor_item_id. When the program saves, item_id and vendor_id save but vendor_item_id does not save. I have tried every online source but cannot seem to get that one attribute to save. I am using rails 4. Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Did my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    @vendor = params["item"]["vendors"]


   if @item.save
       @item.create_vendor_item(@vendor.id => vendor).save
       redirect_to @item
   else 
       render 'new'
   end
  end
```

Comment: Still is not saving that one attribute? I appreciate the help though.

Comment: @user3552703 Can you paste the params value when u are in create action .

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LHVt6WUxJLQzwl9FOIeuOnpWZVCKavEKsTEYew+PWuU=", "item"=>{"item_id"=>"1987", "item"=>{"vendor_item_id"=>"Test-1800"}, "name"=>"ZR700", "category"=>"HDD", "description"=>"Fast", "reorder_level"=>"7", "quantity"=>"11", "price"=>"39.99"}, "vendors"=>{"id"=>"76547"}, "commit"=>"Update Item", "id"=>"1987"}

Comment: If I make the fields_for :vendor_item then the parameters look like  Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"LHVt6WUxJLQzwl9FOIeuOnpWZVCKavEKsTEYew+PWuU=",
 "item"=>{"item_id"=>"1988",
 "vendor_item_attributes"=>{"vendor_item_id"=>"YZF-1500"},
 "name"=>"Seagate HDD",
 "category"=>"HDD",
 "description"=>"1TB harddrive ",
 "reorder_level"=>"8",
 "quantity"=>"9",
 "price"=>"89.99"},
 "vendors"=>{"id"=>"76547"},
 "commit"=>"Create Item"}

Comment: When I use the edited answer I get undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass. Then if I resend the data, I get a Mysql2 duplicate error for primary key

Answer (score 0):

You haven't saving the result in an instance variable in `create` action.

Try giving like this in your create action.

```
def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    vendor = params[:vendors][:id]
    @item_vendor = @item.build_vendor_item(:vendor_id => vendor)

    if @item.save
      redirect_to @item
    else 
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Would I then use f.fields_for @item_vendor with this change?

Comment: @user3552703 yes give it a try.

Comment: When I do that I get this as my params:  Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"LHVt6WUxJLQzwl9FOIeuOnpWZVCKavEKsTEYew+PWuU=",
 "item"=>{"item_id"=>"37465",
 "vendor_item"=>{"vendor_item_id"=>"HYT-3456"},
 "name"=>"Txz2",
 "category"=>"Laptop",
 "description"=>"Touchscreen",
 "reorder_level"=>"5",
 "quantity"=>"15",
 "price"=>"229.99"},
 "vendors"=>{"id"=>"76547"},
 "commit"=>"Create Item"}  It shows vendor_item => vendor_item_id is what it is suppose to be but still does not save it to the database?

Comment: @user3552703 you are not saving the `@item_vendor`.try @item_vendor.save after this line `@item_vendor = @item.build_vendor_item(:vendor_id => vendor)`

Comment: Still is not saving? I just updated the code on here to show the changes.

Comment: If I take out the f.field_for and make it just fields_for it takes the vendor_item => vendor_item_id and places it after the item attributes. When vendor_item => vendor_item_id is in the item parameters than it gives me an unpermitted parameter vendor_item. If I take out the f. than that error goes away since vendor_item is not an attribute in item